# How to locate mutli-byte symbol characters in text strings?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I have textual data, stored in a SQLite database table, that includes em-dashes, at least I think that's what they are.  I'd like to identify words that have one in the results.

I am able to retrieve the text with em-dashes and pass it to a browser for display, and it displays as expected. I can't see it in Konsole though but I assume the command line interface just can't display it.

It also appears to be more than one byte in length.

My question is, how can I test for this character in the text?

The code I've been trying is below, and it does not locate the symbol. It does find other text though.

The column `$text_content` is a string of text, which I am separating by word. More precisely, by space character because SQLite returns the string as a list.  Consequently, punctuation marks and other symbols are usually prefixed or suffixed to the English word.  I want to record the word with and without punctuation, and capture the presence of certain symbols, such as the em-dash, as if they were words.  The purpose is to build a separate table from which to more quickly perform text searches for words and combinations of words.

Also if there is a better method of performing text searches across rows of text within SQLite, please let me know what they are. It seems inefficient to search through every row for each search. So, I'm trying to build the equivalent of a Biblical concordance that points to every row that contains the word, and then use the intersection of the "pointers" to determine the rows that meet all the search requirements.

I'll need to find all matches, not just the first, but this was just for testing.

Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

```
dbt eval $sql {
 set l $text_content
 foreach word $l {
   if { [string first — $word] > -1 } { puts "Got one!" }
   chan puts stdout "[incr i] $word"
 }

 set i 0
 chan puts stdout "\n\n"
}
```

---

**After using code from @Shawn.**
The lmap command isn't even in my Tcl book, at least not in the index. Anyway, I used the code example on one of the strings that has what I thought was an em dash; and I suppose it is not a true em dash because that ASCII code is 151 and what is returned are three codes for the dash--226 128 148.  When I extract the string from SQLite and display it in a browser, using Tcl as a local server, it displays a dash of some sort; but these ASCII codes are a Latin a with circumflex, Euro sign, and right double quote. Konsole displays the a with circumflex when write to stdout from Tcl.

I know next to nothing about multi-byte characters, except that they have been causing me issues in a number of areas. Something must've went wrong in writing the data to the database because if I go back to the source and copy it into Kate and run it on that string rather than retrieving it from SQLite, the code for the dash is 8212.

I suppose, if this is the way all such dashes are coded in these strings, I could search for them by code set, like searching for a string within a string, and replace them with a real em dash.

I have tried using this code; and it appears to work. However, some of the words that have an em dash also have a semi-colon; and when the word is modified and changed in the list using `lset`, it is added as a list itself of length one. How can I get it to just be the word that ends with a semi-colon? I added that as a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961022/working-with-lists-that-have-words-ending-in-semi-colons).

For example, if the original was `word—;` and I fix the odd dash to be a 151 and modify the list, it appears as `{ word word {word—;} word }`.

What I'd like to know, here, is is this a reliable method of handling the multi-bytes in Tcl, for this particular case at least?

I see that using 151 is stupid because this is not ASCII encoded. When I use 8212, and pass the text to a browser from Tcl, the browser throws an error of `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1 column 49 of the JSON data`. Thus, whatever the reason is for this must be why the em dash was encoded as three bytes at the start.  If I pass the three-byte version to the browser, it accepts it and displays it as expected. Thus, I do not understand something important and basic here. The issue seems to arise when convert this to binary to pass to the browser.

Thank you.

```
proc Emdash {} {
  global cps string pseudo_emdash
  set l [expr { [llength $cps] - 2}]
  set k -1; # Character position in cps.
  set b 0; # Count blank characters for word position.
  set p 0; # Track position of last blank for character position.

  while { [incr k] < $l } {
    if { [lindex $cps $k] == 32 } { incr b; set p $k }
    for { set x [lindex $cps [set i $k]]; set y [lindex $pseudo_emdash [set j 0]] } \
        { $x == $y && $j < 3 } { incr i; incr j } { }
    if { $j == 3 } {
      chan puts stdout "A match begins at index $k after blank no. $b."
      chan puts stdout [lrange $cps $k [expr {$i-1}]]
      chan puts stdout "[lindex $string $b] [expr {$k-$p-1}]"
      set new [string replace [lindex $string $b] [set z [expr {$k-$p-1}]] $z+2 [format %c 151]]
      chan puts stdout $new
      lset string $b $new
      chan puts stdout $string
    }
  }
}

set pseudo_emdash {226 128 148}
set string ""
set cps ""

dbt eval $sql {
  global string cps
  chan puts stdout $text_content
  set string $text_content
  set cps [lmap c [split $text_content ""] { scan $c %c }]
  Emdash
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the character you're looking for is present, and not some other dash character that's rendered similarly? Gotta look at the actual codepoints (`set cps [lmap c [split $string ""] { scan $c %c }]`).

Comment: You might also look into the sqlite FTS5 module for efficient text searching.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks. I'll confirm that and thanks for the code sample (I'm new to Tcl).  I was just reading about the FTS5 module.  It seems quite powerful.  If it would be equally fast for my relatively small amount of data, it might be a good choice.  My text strings are between only 11 and 556 characters in length; and there are a little over 31,000 of them per search. However, the results of that first search usually become the input for another query to generate the final results.

Comment: Would something like ` SELECT rowid, val FROM example WHERE val REGEXP '[^ -~]';` be good enough to find such characters?

Comment: FTS5 is faster than most self-made indexing alternatives, providing you're searching for words. It has some very clever index building behind the scenes. Apart from that, Tcl and SQLite both merrily work with unicode characters (at least in the basic multilingual plane) so it's worth just trying and seeing if things work. That includes handling regular expressions.

Comment: @DonalFellows @Shawn I used the code sample to check the characters and wrote the results in the question. I attempted to search for the multiple bytes as looking for a string within a string, in order to replace the odd dash with a single ASCII 151 Em dash; and it appears to work, except for one issue.  When a word has a terminating semi-colon, and `lset` is used to replace the original word, it is replaced as a single-item list itself rather than just a word. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: That issue will be because `;` is a Tcl metacharacter (command terminator) and the standard list formatter _also_ quotes all Tcl metacharacters so the result isn't just a list but also a surprise-free Tcl command.

Comment: When using UTF-8, characters are a variable number of bytes. Characters with codes up to 127 (the ASCII subset) are a single byte, ones with larger codes use several bytes. Tcl regards characters as the important thing, not (usually) bytes, and hides the shenanigans with encodings for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three comparatively common types of dashes: `-` (minus/hyphen), `–` (en-dash), and `—` (em-dash). OK, they look identical in that font; here they are in running text: “-”, “–”, and “—”. Their Unicode codes are 45, 8211, and 8212 respectively. Only the first is in ASCII; the other two are not. A consequence is that they take multiple bytes to express in the (very common these days) UTF-8 encoding, and indeed the dashes take three bytes each (that this is so is usually uninteresting except when things have gone fairly wrong). Only the first is really used all that much in programming, and the other two are often trickier to type (albeit not on this machine).

In Tcl, to match those characters without typing them, you use `\u2013` and `\u2014` (those numbers are in hexadecimal). You can use that in standard Tcl code or in regular expressions; it works the same in both places.

```sh
# Print an em-dash
puts "abc \u2014 def"

# Test if a string has an en-dash or em-dash in it
if {[regexp {[\u2013\u2014]} $inputString]} {
    puts "found one"
}
```

I can't remember how exactly SQLite handles character escaping, but it most certainly prefers to store text as UTF-8. It should just work pretty well with Tcl.

---

The problem in your code (`lmap` is a command introduced in Tcl 8.6) is that you're converting incautiously between a string and a list; lists are strings, yes, but with *very* particular quoting rules, and those rules are particularly strict when generating a list's string form (e.g., after you've modified the list with `lset` or `lappend`). In particular, ***all*** Tcl metacharacters get quoted one way or another (usually with braces, sometimes with backslashes). The code to parse a list from a string is much laxer.

The way to sort this out is to `split` the input sentence, apply the transformation to each <del>word</del> item in the list, and then `join` the result.

```sh
join [lmap word [split $input] { ... }]
```

That's the framework of what you're trying to do; you've just got to add in the `...`, perhaps with `string map`:

```sh
puts [join [lmap word [split $input] {
    string map {\u2013 - \u2014 -} $word
}]]
```

Comment: If you're seeing the UTF-8 bytes directly, something weird is going on. `encoding convertfrom utf-8` might help.

Comment: I apologize for wasting everyone's time.  I found the source of my issue, which primarily is my stupidity, then that I was storing the strings as binary in SQLite.  Once I fixed that,, I can search on an em dash using the single code or typed character.  One last question in this regard please? If the table that contains the strings will be used only to pass back to the browser for display, does it make sense to store them as binary? I'll just need to encode each to UTF-8 to build the concordance table which should be stored as UTF-8 since it will be searched against to get "pointers"?