# Working with lists that have words ending in semi-colons?

Tags: tcl

Is there a way to add strings (words) that end with a semi-colon to a list without it being a single-item list itself?

I'm working with strings and breaking them into words; and the punctuation often is attached as a suffix. I need to have the words both ways, that is with and without the punctuation.

Is it okay to simply let it a be a list within a list, and just reference all of the words as if they were single-item lists? It appears to work. Or is there a better method altogether?

Thank you.

```
set list { a; b c d }
chan puts stdout $list; # a; b c d

set new "b;"
lset list 1 $new

chan puts stdout $list; # {a;} {b;} c d
chan puts stdout [lindex [lindex $list 1] 0]; # b;
chan puts stdout [lindex [lindex $list 3] 0]; # d
chan puts stdout [lindex $new 0]; # b;
```

Comment: FYI: `chan puts stdout [lindex [lindex {{a;} {b;} c d} 1] 0]` has the same output as `chan puts stdout [lindex {{a;} {b;} c d} 1]`. That extra `lindex` does nothing in this case. Somewhat confused as to why the extra braces for `a;` appear after `lset`. Maybe internal type changed from string to list, making `puts` behave differently. Still, the braces are not necessary to my knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working with strings and breaking them into words

It is important to use `split` for this step, other than that, you should be fine using the so-produced list by appending to it. The various list commands will make sure that special characters (your `;`) will be protected from being ill-interpreted.

From the Tcl perspective, there is no difference between a single-element list `{a;}` and an atomic string `a;`. To quote the [Tclers' Wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/list):

> No program can tell the difference between the string "a" and the
> one-element list "a", because the one-element list "a" is the string
> "a".

Don't let the curly braces confuse you.

Comment: Curly braces are a quoting mechanism. If you don't want them at the end, `join` undoes what `split` does.